# Pagination with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I just can't seem to get pagination in Wordpress to work... I have tried for weeks to get it going but it seems to be impossible :(. Is it doable, in that case how?

this is my Wp_Query:

```
$all_posts = new WP_Query(array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
));
```

And this is how I output it:

```
if ($all_posts->have_posts()): while ($all_posts->have_posts()) : $all_posts->the_post();

  // content rendered here

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I can't see any pagination code in your given code snippet. Read https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fantastic article showed the way!
http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/19/paging-and-custom-wordpress-loops/

Answer (score 0):

For normal pagination at it's most basic level:

```
<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
```

You can use one of these plugins to add numbered pagination functionality.  As of now, this isn't supported natively in WordPress.  That would be a good reference point to start with if you're trying to write it from scratch.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/

Comment: Then what is this <?php posts_nav_link(); ?> supposed to do if not pagination?

All I wan't is an older post and newer post button.

Comment: Revised for basic pagination

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$all_posts = new WP_Query(array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
   'paged=' => $paged
));
```

and after the loop add this:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries', $preNewsPosts->max_num_pages) ?></div>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;', $preNewsPosts->max_num_pages) ?></div>
</div>
```